# Xamarin Android Draw EditText on Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-edittext, xamarin.android, drawing

I have subclass of `ImageView` on which I can draw (pen, rect, elipse etc..) and add `EditText` subviews (draggable and can be rotated).

Problem is when I want to get final image I'm not sure how to merge those `EditText` into new image, because all the tools are drawing directly on canvas while I need to draw `EditText` texts at the end, since they need to be draggable and changable before user clicks Save.

After many different approaches, this one is most correct but it doesn't work if the text is rotated by some degree.

```
    public Bitmap GetFinalBitmap()
    {
        this.DrawingCacheEnabled = false;
        this.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;

        var finalImage = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(GetDrawingCache(true));
        foreach (var item in this.pathLists)
        {
            if (item.TextView != null)
            {
                item.TextView.BuildDrawingCache(true);
                var txt = item.TextView.GetDrawingCache(true);
                finalImage = Overlay(finalImage, txt, item.TextView.GetX(), item.TextView.GetY());
            }
        }

        return finalImage;
    }

    public Bitmap Overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2, float x, float y)
    {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height, bmp1.GetConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.DrawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.DrawBitmap(bmp2, x, y, null);
        return bmOverlay;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated (update of solution or maybe new approach on how to draw `EditText` with correct coordinates on `ImageView's` bitmap).

Answer (score 0):

Basically all I had to do was draw second bitmap (one of the `EditText`) using matrix. Here is updated code that works even for rotated `EditText`.

```
    public Bitmap Overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2, float x, float y, float rotation)
    {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height, bmp1.GetConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.DrawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
        var matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.Reset();
        if (rotation > 0)
            matrix.PostRotate(rotation, bmp2.Width / 2, bmp2.Height / 2);
        matrix.PostTranslate(x, y);    
        canvas.DrawBitmap(bmp2, matrix, null);
        return bmOverlay;
    }
```